# The one-loop propagator correction with cutoff in Yukawa theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

On page 409 of Peskin and Shroeder.
The one-loop propagator correction with dimensional regularization in Yukawa theory is:
$$\hspace{-190pt}i\cal{M}:=$$ 
[image]
$$\hspace{-150pt} = \frac{-2ig^2}{(4\pi)^2}(-p^2)\left( \frac{1}{2-d/2} +\log\frac{1}{-p^2}+C \right). \tag{12.33} $$
And the renormalization condition in this section is: 
\begin{cases}
i\mathcal{M} + i(p^2\delta_Z-\delta_m) =0 \quad\text{at}\quad p^2=-M^2 \\
\frac{d}{dp^2}\left[i\mathcal{M}+i(p^2\delta_Z-\delta_m)\right] =0 \quad\text{at}\quad p^2=-M^2 \tag{12.30}
\end{cases}
where $M$ is the renormalization scale, $\delta_Z$ the field strength renormalization counterterm, and $\delta_m$ the mass renormalization counterterm.

> In the following discussion, we will assume the use
>   of dimensional regularization. However, to emphasize the physical role of the
>   cutoff, we will write expressions of the form (12.33) as
>   $$i\mathcal{M}= \frac{-2ig^2}{(4\pi)^2}(-p^2)\left( \log\frac{\Lambda^2}{-p^2}+C \right) \tag{12.34}$$
>   The logarithmically divergent terms proportional to $p^2$ will agree with the divergences obtained with a momentum cutoff; the constant terms will not agree, but these will drop out of our nal results.

By dimensional analysis one can guess the pole $\frac{1}{2-d/2}$  corresponds to $\log \Lambda^2$ in (12.34).
And I calculated with cutoff.
First from
$$ \hspace{-80pt} i\mathcal{M}= -4g^2 \int_0^1 dx \int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{l^2+\Delta}{(l^2-\Delta)^2} \tag{10.33} $$ 
(where $\Delta=m_f^2-x(1-x)p^2$, and here I've already set $d=4$), performing a Wick rotation $l^0=il_E^0$,
\begin{alignat}{2}
&=&& -4g^2 \int_0^1 dx \frac{-l_E^2+\Delta}{(l_E^2+\Delta)^2} \\
&=&& -4ig^2 \left(\int\frac{d\Omega_4}{(2\pi)^4} \right) \int_0^1 dx \int_0^{\infty}\,dl_E l_E^3 \frac{-l_E^2+\Delta}{(l_E^2+\Delta)^2} 
\end{alignat}
setting $s=l_E^2+\Delta$,
$$ l_Edl_E=\frac{1}{2}ds $$
$$ \therefore \int_0^{\infty}\,dl_E l_E^3 \frac{-l_E^2+\Delta}{(l_E^2+\Delta)^2} 
= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Delta}^{\Lambda^2+\Delta}ds \frac{(s-\Delta)(-s+2\Delta)}{s^2} \\
= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Delta}^{\Lambda^2+\Delta}ds \left( \frac{(-s^2+3\Delta s-2\Delta^2)}{s^2} \right)
= \frac{1}{2} \left[ -s+3\Delta\log s+\frac{2\Delta^2}{s} \right]_{\Delta}^{\Lambda^2+\Delta}
\sim -\frac{1}{2}\Lambda^2 $$
This doesn't agree  with (12.34).
**Question 1**: Why is that? Have I made mistakes somewhere in the calculation?
**Question 2**: Why will the constant terms drop out of our nal results?
Any answer to at least one question would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This quotation in this post is a few lines below on the same page of the quotation of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310862/an-analytic-continuation-of-the-one-loop-propagator-correction-in-yukawa-theory).